# How to create xml dynamically?

Tags: python, xml

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 var3 = raw_input("Enter the root Element: \n")
 root = ET.Element(var3) 
 var4 = raw_input("Enter the sub root Element: \n")
 doc = ET.SubElement(root, var4)   

 no_of_rows=input("Enter the number of Element for XML files: -    \n")

 def printme():

    var = raw_input("Enter Element: - \n")
    var1 = raw_input("Enter Data: - \n")

    ET.SubElement(doc, var).text =var1

    return;

    for num in range(0, no_of_rows):
        printme()

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    file = raw_input("Enter File Name: - \n")
    tree.write(file)

    ET.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)         
    print "Xml file Created..!!"
```

I want to create xml dynamically using python.

How to create multiple sub roots?

---

I am giving file name from the console to store written elements in xml. It is giving this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

What should I do?

Comment: you already created xml file. What is the problem ? Do you need `for` loop to create more elements ? Or `ET.parse("filename.xml")` to read file ?

Comment: I am giving file name from the console to store written elements in xml but its giving error that "TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'" . What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You are taking no. of elements from user but you are not using it.
Use a loop and get element details from user within the loop as shown below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
try:
    no_of_rows=int(input("Enter the number of Element for XML files: -    \n"))
    root = input("Enter the root Element: \n")
    root_element = ET.Element(root)
    for _ in range(1, no_of_rows):
        tag = input("Enter Element: - \n")
        value = input("Enter Data: - \n")    
        ET.SubElement(root_element, tag).text = value

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root_element)
    tree.write("filename.xml")

    print("Xml file Created..!!")
except ValueError:
    print("Value Error")
except:
    print("Exception Occuured")
    enter code here
```

I hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: After entering root name it showing exception that "Exception occured". Which code should be inserted ?

Comment: @MahaveerBubanale The code I have given here is for Python 3 and you are using Python 2+. There is a slight difference between `input` in Python 3 and Python 2+, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x . If you change `input` to `raw_input` in my code then it would not throw any exception.

Comment: Can i modify the same file with diff operation? and how?

Comment: @MahaveerBubanale - for modification of an XML refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file or please post specific query and your code that you have written so far...

Answer (score -1):

If you want create xml you may just do this:

```
from lxml import etree
try:
   root_text = raw_input("Enter the root Element: \n")
   root = etree.Element(root_text)
   child_tag = raw_input("Enter the child tag Element: \n")
   child_text = raw_input("Enter the child text Element: \n")
   child = etree.Element(child_text )
   child.text =child_text 
   root.append(child)
   with open('file.xml', 'w') as f:
      f.write(etree.tostring(root))
      f.close()
except ValueError:
    print("Occured Error")
```

Or if you want dynamic length you just use for loop.

Comment: Encountered "root_text" at line 3, column 1. Was expecting:     "<INDENT>" . showing error

Comment: In this case can you please upvote and accept answer?

Comment: How above script should be modify and perform operations dynamically?